# Find continuous $f$ that satisfies $f(0)=1$, $f(m+n+1)=f(m)+f(n)$

Tags: functional-equations

Let $f$ be a continuous real-to-real function that satisfies $f(0)=1$ and 
$$f(m+n+1)=f(m)+f(n)$$
for all $m,n\in{\mathbb R}$.
Show $f (x) = x + 1$ for all $x$.

What is the solution?

Source: Solving mathematical problems a personal perspective, exercise 3.1

Comment: What is the question  and where is your work? Why do keep writing $m$ and $n$ and then say for all $x$? Please edit the question carefully so that we can understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppuse $f$ is continuous with $f(0)=1$ and satisfies for each $x$, $y$:
$$f(x+y+1)=f(x)+f(y)\tag1$$
Then $f(x)=f(x-1+0+1)\stackrel{(1)}=f(x-1)+f(0)=f(x-1)+1$, so $$f(x-1)=f(x)-1.\tag2$$ Define $$g(x):=f(x)-1.\tag3$$ Then for all $x$, $y$ we have
$$\begin{align}
g(x+y)\stackrel{(3)} =&f(x+y)-1\\
=&f(x+y-1+1)-1\\
\stackrel{(1)}=&
f(x)+f(y-1)-1\\
\stackrel{(2)}=&f(x)+f(y)-1-1\\
\stackrel{(3)}=&g(x)+g(y).
\end{align}$$
We've shown that $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$.  So $g$ satisfies the [Cauchy functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/423492/215011). Since $g$ is continuous, conclude $g(x)=cx$ for some constant $c$. Plug this back into (3) to find $f(x)=cx+1$. The only value of $c$ that allows $f$ to satisfy (2) is $c=1$ and therefore $f(x)=x+1$. Check that this choice of $f$ satisfies (1).

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

$f(m+n+1+1)$

$=f(m+1)+f(n)$

$=f(m)+f(n)+f(0)$

$=f(m+n+1)+1$

Then,

$f(x+1)=f(x)+1$

So,

$f(x)=x+1$

Comment: Are all the criteria of the desired function met with this choice in f? If so, then you've done everything the problem asked.

Comment: If x is an integer, my choice in f will meet the criteria. But if x is a rational number or a real number, I don't find  how to show f meet the criteria.